# Finding string after searched string in textbox

Tags: vb.net, sockets, textbox

I have been working an application that uses sockets to connect to a switch and issues commands. Afterwards the data read back from the switch is put in a text file and lines that contain a certain string, for this instance `"GE1"`, are placed in a textbox like the following.

```
GE1/0/1              UP   1G(a)   F(a)   A    101  To Station 1
GE1/0/2              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 2
GE1/0/3              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 3
GE1/0/4              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 4
GE1/0/5              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 5
GE1/0/6              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 6
GE1/0/7              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 7
GE1/0/8              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 8
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/9              DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 9
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/10             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 10
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/11             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 11
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/12             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 12
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/13             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 13
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/14             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 14
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/15             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 15
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/16             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 16
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/17             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 17
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/18             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 18
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/19             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 19
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/20             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 20
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/21             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 21
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/22             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 22
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/23             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 23
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/24             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 24
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/25             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 25
  ---- More ----[16D                [16DGE1/0/26             DOWN auto    A      A    1    To Station 26
```

The problem is the following: I want to take the different text after the GE1/0/? and have each individual text applied to labels so the info is viewable on a small form.

example:

```
Label1 = "UP" 
Label2 = "1G(a)
'and so on until it reads to the end of the line before moving to the next line and
'repeating with the next group of labels.
```

*Note that the information will whether if something is connected to the stations or not.*

On a side note: I have tried using `Textbox1.text = Textbox1.text.Replace("  ---- More ----[16D         [16D", "")` with and without `.Trim` but it does not remove the text. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one point you refer to it as a `text file` then a `textbox`.  That would appear to be a multiline textbox, so you should be working with the lines array.  Even better would be to load the file to an array, process it, *then* post to a TextBox or parse it directly.

For trimming the first part, this chop the first part however long it is and whether or not it is really spaces or tabs or something else in between.

```
    Dim lines = TextBox1.Lines    ' or from file

    Dim ndx As Integer

    For n As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(n).StartsWith("GE1") = False Then
            ndx = lines(n).IndexOf("GE1")
            lines(n) = lines(n).Substring(ndx, lines(n).Length - ndx)
        End If
    Next

    TextBox1.Lines = lines
```

Since this *appears* to be more or less fixed length fields, you should be able to use your favorite text parser to chop it up once the row data is cleaned up.  I would advise parsing it into a class so that you can fetch back whatever nugget you want for whichever data element.  As an example of parsing though, this will chop it up into the *apparent* fields and display in a `ListView`.

```
Dim ndx As Integer
Dim tmp As String
Dim lvi As ListViewItem

For n As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If lines(n).StartsWith("GE1") = False Then
        ndx = lines(n).IndexOf("GE1")
        lines(n) = lines(n).Substring(ndx, lines(n).Length - ndx)
    End If

    tmp = lines(n)
    ' col 1 = 10 chars (approx)
    lvi = New ListViewItem(tmp.Substring(0, 10).Trim)
    tmp = tmp.Substring(10, tmp.Length - 10).Trim()

    ' col 2 = up to 4 chars
    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp.Substring(0, 4))
    tmp = tmp.Substring(4, tmp.Length - 4).Trim()

    ' col 3 = up to 5 chars "1G(a)"
    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp.Substring(0, 5))
    tmp = tmp.Substring(5, tmp.Length - 5).Trim()

    ' col 4 = up to 4 chars "F(a)"
    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp.Substring(0, 4))
    tmp = tmp.Substring(4, tmp.Length - 4).Trim()

    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp.Substring(0, 1))
    tmp = tmp.Substring(1, tmp.Length - 1).Trim()

    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp.Substring(0, 3))
    tmp = tmp.Substring(3, tmp.Length - 3).Trim()

    lvi.SubItems.Add(tmp)

    lv1.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

Note: the data sample provided is not comprehensive and HTML formatting may have imposed some changes, so the exact code may have to be tweaked.  Otherwise:

[image][image]